# Jquery smooth scrolling: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm trying to script a backtotop button which will be situated sitewide in the footer, for some reason it's returning "Cannot read property 'top' of undefined".
Any help would be great, cheers.

JQUERY

```
$( '#backtotop' ).on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var target = '#'+$(this).data('target')
            $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
        }, 1000);
 });
```

HTML

```
    <a href="#" data-target="navigation"><span id="backtotop"><img id="upwardarrow" src="/img/upwardarrow.png"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var target = '#'+$(this).parent().data('target');
```

`this` in your code refers to the span which does not have `data-target`, you have to access it from the parent `<a>`

Or modify your html like this:

```
<a href="#" id="backtotop" data-target="navigation"><span><img id="upwardarrow" src="/img/upwardarrow.png"></span></a>
```

Move the `id="backtotop"` to the `<a>` tag and don't need to change the js.

Comment: Thanks, works, will accept as answer ASAP. In the meantime, could you explain why it works?

Comment: I see what you mean, as per your update. I didn't notice that, thanks mate. I'll modify the html instead. :-)

Comment: @Jack Williams: you're wellcome. I'm glad it helps.

Comment: Oh crap, completely forgot to accept answer, sorted it now, sorry dude.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  $(document).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Comment: How do you set a speed on this?

Comment: @user1380540 could you elaborate on what you mean by speed? Are you referring to the scroll speed or the delay before the scroll starts?

Comment: The scroll speed

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to close off the line with **;** 
Also, I changed the target definition.

```
$( '#backtotop' ).on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).parents().attr("href");
        alert(target);
            $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top;
        }, 1000);
 });
```

Tested and working.

Comment: I was getting an 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;' error after the .top

Even after fixing that this code does not scroll on the page and doesn't give me any further errors